# How can you zoom in on text within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a text editor with an `iframe` that has the `contenteditable` attribute on. I added a zoom feature, that zooms in on the `iframe`. Here's the code: `document.getElementById("textareathingy").style.zoom = percentage;` When I use the zoom in feature, it makes the `iframe` "bigger" but the size of the text remains the same. Can someone point me in the right direction to make the text within the `iframe` also be zoomed in.

```
<html>
<body>
<button id = "btn" onclick = "zoom()">Click me!</button>
<iframe name = "textfield" id = "textareathingy" style = "border: 1px black solid; width: 100px; height: 100px"></iframe>
</body>
<script>
window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML = "random text";
var percentage = 2;
function zoom() {
document.getElementById("textareathingy").style.zoom = percentage;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Plase can you post the whole code? Or at least a big part of it. Is kind of hard figure out how to do it without the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this instead:

```
document.getElementById("textareathingy").style.transform = "scale(" + percentage + ")";
```